# Ruby Yard documentation: how to add a "verbatim" (to generate something like a <pre> tag)

Tags: ruby, rdoc, yard

I want a piece of code, like a hash, to display with fixed typeface on the resulting html. Suppose this is the contents of my file:

```
=begin

One example of valid hash to this function is:
{
    :name => "Engelbert",
    :id  => 1345
}
=end
def f hash_param
  # ...
end
```

How to instruct yard (using the default of the version `0.9.15`) so a `yard doc file.rb`  will generate, for the hash example, the equivalent of adding 4 backslashes to the markdown format, or 4 starting empty spaces to stackoverflow, or the  `<pre>` tag in html, resulting in a verbatim/fixed typeface format in the resulting html?

Expected output:

```
One example of valid hash to this function is:
{
    :name => "Engelbert",
    :id  => 1345
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

```
> gem install redcarpet
> yard doc --markup-provider redcarpet --markup markdown - file.rb
```

Should wrap the contents of `file.rb` within a `<pre>` tag, producing this [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSFWX.png).

---

Use [@example](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#example)

> Show an example snippet of code for an object. The first line is an optional title.

```
# @example One example of valid hash to this function is:
#   {
#       :name => "Engelbert",
#       :id  => 1345
#   }
def f hash_param
  # ...
end
```

Comment: ok, maybe the question was confusing, but, although what I what to display in the case above is an example, but I would like the solution to work for other cases too. Example of other cases: an ASCII art image displaying a super cow.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts and I really like the supercow there... but that's definitively not the answer -- the source code isn't to be output. I think that's better to admit that it's probably not possible to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't get your question:

> the equivalent of adding 4 backslashes to the markdown format, or 4 starting empty spaces to stackoverflow

If I use the 4 starting empty spaces in my code like this:

```
=begin

One example of valid hash to this function is:
    {
        :name => "Engelbert",
        :id  => 1345
    }
=end
def f hash_param
  # ...
end
```

then I get

[image]

But maybe you can also use `@option`:

```
@param hash_param
@option hash_param [String] :name The name of...
@option hash_param [Integer] :id The id of...
```

and you get:

[image]

Disclaimer: I used yard 0.9.26 for my examples.